# How to take key-values from given json in spring boot java

Tags: java, hashmap

What is the code for take key-values from given json, We can use Hash Map? how to write the code?Need to change pojo class?I need to take 'startTime' and 'endTime' from JSON

```
My input Json 
    {
    "active" : 0,
    "id" : 3,
    "doctorId" :8,
    "hospitalId" : 55,
    "timeSlot" : [
         { "startTime": "10",
           "endTime": "12" 
         },
         { "startTime": "3",
           "endTime": "5" 
         }
        ]
    }
```

My code

```
List slot = customDuty.getTimeSlot();
                    int count = 0;      
                    while (slot.size() > count) {
                        logger.info("checking"+slot.get(count));
                       count++;

                    }
```

PojoClass

```
private List timeSlot ;

    public List getTimeSlot() {
        return timeSlot;
    }
    public void setTimeSlot(List timeSlot) {
        this.timeSlot = timeSlot;
    }
```

output

```
checking{startTime=10, endTime=12}
checking{startTime=3, endTime=5}
```

Comment: Output of what code? What is the type if TimeSlot?

Comment: Basics of this would be : deserialise it, if you do it correctly you can easily access TimeSlot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most java style would be to create a TimeSlot pojo

```java
class TimeSlot {

  private int startTime;
  private int endTime;

  // getters and setters
}
```

And then have in your main entity

```
class MainEntity {

  private List<TimeSlot> timeSlot;

  // getters and setters
}
```

And then you let spring (jersey) parse it for you.

Usage:

```java
mainEntity.getTimeSlots().foreach(timeSlot -> logger.log(
   "checking\{startTime={}, endTime={}\}",
   timeSlot.getStartTime(),
   timeSlot.getEndTime(),
))
```

But indeed you could take the approach of having a `HashMap<String, Integer>` as the type of `timeSlot`, and access trough its keys.

```
class MainEntity {

  private List<HashMap<String, Integer>> timeSlot;

  // getters and setters
}
```

```java
mainEntity.getTimeSlots().foreach(timeSlot -> logger.log(
   "checking\{startTime={}, endTime={}\}",
   timeSlot.get("startTime"),
   timeSlot.getEndTime("endTime"),
))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with SpringBoot java you need to add Jackson dependencies in your POM

`<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 </dependency>`

And then you need map the json file with your POJO

```
public class ObjectMapperDemo {
 public Hospital readJsonWithObjectMapper() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    Hospital hos = objectMapper.readValue(new File("hospital.json"), Hospital.class);
    return hospital;
} 
}
```

The hospital entity class is define as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Hospital {
private boolean active;
private int id;
private int doctorId;
private int hospitalId;
private List<TimeSlot> timeSlot;`

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getDoctorId() {
    return doctorId;
}

public void setDoctorId(int doctorId) {
    this.doctorId = doctorId;
}

public int getHospitalId() {
    return hospitalId;
}

public void setHospitalId(int hospitalId) {
    this.hospitalId = hospitalId;
}

public List<TimeSlot> getTimeSlot() {
    return timeSlot;
}

public void setTimeSlot(List<TimeSlot> timeSlot) {
    this.timeSlot = timeSlot;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hospital{" +
            "active=" + active +
            ", id=" + id +
            ", doctorId=" + doctorId +
            ", hospitalId=" + hospitalId +
            ", timeSlot=" + timeSlot +
            '}';
}
```

}